# Is Managed Navigation part of the Standard CAL for sharepoint on-premise 2013

Tags: 2013, licensing, managed-navigation, farm, cal

I am working on a sharepoint server on-premise 2013, which have standard CAL license. and i added a new enterprise wiki site collection, where this enterprise wiki site collection will have Managed Navigation enabled by default as follow:-

[image]

so seems Managed Navigation is available inside standard CAL, but i was reading this link about the differences between Enterprise CAL & Standard CAL for sharepoint on-premise 2013

http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/

which is mentioning that Managed Navigation is only available inside the Enterprise CAL,, but based on my test (as described above) that Standard CAL will have Managed Navigation available... so can anyone advice on this ? is the link providing wrong info ? or Managed Navigation which it is talking about is different from the one i am talking about (which is available inside my Enterprise wiki site collection)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, Managed Navigation is part of the SharePoint Standard Cal.

Check below official technet article for the correct information. You have to scroll down all the way bottom of the page and look for **Feature availability across SharePoint on-premises plans**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: so this link http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/ is it 100% correct ?

Comment: Yes, I always check technet as that's official

Answer (score 2):

As per MSDN official article metadata navigation will be available in both standard and enterprise but foundation doesn`t. Here is the article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint__cloud/2013/01/09/sharepoint-2013-onpremise-edition-comparison-chart/

Comment: so seems the info inside this link http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/ is not 100% correct? at-least since it mentioned that managed navigation is only provided as part of the enterprise CAL ?

Comment: Yes. It is always recommended to follow the MSDN official article when change in version and feature comparison.